# How to get Joomla's breadcrumb to display correct path to K2 item?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, breadcrumbs, joomla-k2

I'm almost done with developing a quite complex Joomla website and I have a very irritating bug with the breadcrumb. I'll try to explain it the simplest way possible.

I mix Joomla Articles and K2 items in order for my website to work as it should.

I have the following architecture :

### About

- Testimonies (K2 category listing)

### Year X

- Program (Specific article with K2 modules that list the lessons)

  - Lesson 1 (K2 item)
  - Lesson 2...

### Program Life

- Teachers (Joomla category listing)

  - Mr. X (Joomla article)
  - Mr. Y

The user can access the lessons details from the program's page or from a teacher's page.

When you access a lesson's page from the program's page the breadcrumb shows 'Home > Year X > Program > Lesson 1' which is perfectly fine.

When you try to access a lesson's page from a teacher's page the breadcrumb shows 'Home > About > Testimonies > Lesson 1'... which isn't correct.

I use Joomla's breadcrumb module and not K2's.

I'm pretty sure important config details are missing from this post but I'd be really really happy to discuss them with you if you need.

Regards,
Jibou

Answer (score 0):

Joomla will (always?) add the current menu item to the breadcrumbs. From there further down it's up to the extension what will be shown.

So it looks like the links from your teachers page have the "Testimonies" menu item (Itemid) applied and thus Joomla generates breadcrumbs reflecting this menu item.

You should make sure the links from within your Joomla article have the matching Itemid for "Year X" -> "Program" attached, then the breadcrumbs should work.